# nhibernate projection to anonymous type

Tags: c#, nhibernate, group-by, anonymous-types, queryover

I have a query to get count of `Child` objects for a `Parent` object.
I need to convert the result into a `List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>`
Can't figure out.

```
Child childAlias = null;
Parent parentAlias = null;
int[] parentIds = new int[]{1,2,3};

var temp = sess.QueryOver<Parent>()
   .JoinQueryOver(p => p.Children, () => childAlias)
   .Where(c => c.Parent.Id.IsIn(parentIds))
   .Select(Projections.ProjectionList()
      .Add(Projections.GroupProperty(Projections.Property<Parent>(x => x.Id)))
      .Add(Projections.Count(() => childAlias.Id)))
  .List<object[]>();
```

I need this `List<object[]>` to be a `List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>`
I know it involves a `Select` with an annonymous object but can't figure out

Comment: When you debug it, what's the actual type of the items in `temp`?

Comment: with the `List` statement its a list of object arrays,  without the `List ` its an `IQueryOver<Parent, Child>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working query should look like this:

```
Child childAlias = null;
Parent parentAlias = null;
int[] parentIds = new int[] {1, 2, 3};

var temp = sess.QueryOver<Parent>()
    .JoinQueryOver(p => p.Children, () => childAlias)
    .WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.Parent.ID).IsIn(parentIds)
    .Select(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty(Projections.Property<Parent>(x => x.ID)))
        .Add(Projections.Count(() => childAlias.ID)))
    .List<object[]>()
    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int,int>((int)x[0], (int)x[1]));
```

Comment: works! I used the convert from @ilya-kogan 's answer

Answer (score 1):

If every item of the list contains an array of two elements of type `int`, then you can write:

```
var pairs = temp.Select(array => new KeyValuePair(array[0] as int, array[1] as int));
```

If you're not sure there's an `int` there, you can use `Convert.ToInt32` which is safer than `as`.